# Conditionally include CSS in Laravel blade

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

Is it possible to include several style sheet for several HTML element in Laravel blade conditionally in a page ?? Like I would like to include `style.css` for `<div class="first"></div>`,`<div class="second"></div>`, `<div class="third"></div>` and `style1.css` for `<span class="first"></span>`,`<span class="second"></span>`, `<span class="third"></span>` and `style3.css` for `<p class="first"></p>`,`<p class="second"></p>`, `<p class="third"></p>`

Comment: You can of course include multiple style sheets, and you can of course use `@if` and `@else` blade control structures, [the docs are pretty clear](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements).  But I have no idea what you are really asking with your example HTML/CSS.  Please edit your question and try to clarify.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I know `@if` and `@else` of Laravel. But I would like to enable different  style sheet for different HTML element (See Example).  How can I do that ?

Comment: As I said, I don't understand what you are asking, and I think others are having trouble too. Try editing your question and clarifying your question.

Comment: Thanks @Don'tPanic. Could you please Guide me in this regard ?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates what you're trying to do?  I can't guide you on how to ask your question unless I understand the question :-) Edit your question, try describing what you're trying to do in more detail, or in another way.